# What is the purpose of "&" AFTER a nested selector in Less

Tags: css, less

Less

```
.list a{
    .landscape&{
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
.landscape.list a {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Which means "all a tags whose parents have both .landscape and .list"

Less

```
.list a{
    &.landscape{
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
.list a.landscape {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Which means "all a tags which have class 'landscape' and whose parents have .list"

And that makes sense. But if I remove the "a" tag from those selectors, the '&' only changes the concatenation order of .list and .landscape.

What's the point? When should I use `&.class` and when should I use `class.&`?

Comment: The `&` is just 'replaced' with the parent selectors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724861/using-the-ampersand-sass-parent-selector-inside-nested-selectors here shows an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article ["LESS CSS: Secrets of the Ampersand"](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/) details the difference well.  I'll highlight the key uses:

- Attach a class to an existing selector
- Change state based on parent classes
- Filter a nested selector to only match certain elements
- Avoid repetition when selecting repeated elements
- Simplify combinatorial explosions

The latter is my favorite. I've used it to handle some crazy IE issues.  Check this out:

```
/**
 * Add a top border to paragraphs,
 * but remove that border when a preceding paragraph already has one.
 */
p  {
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    & + & {
        border-top: 0;
    }
}
```

I think if you can wrap your mind around what this usage of `&` does, all the other uses become obvious.

Answer (score 7):

The `&` in Less denotes the parent selector. So wherever you put the `&`, it replaces it with the `parent` selector in the CSS, if you have a space before it.

If not, i.e., no space is given before the `&`, it becomes the child and appends the selector with its parent like in your case.

References:

- [Less CSS Secrets-of-the-Ampersand](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/)
- [Parent Selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature)

Comment: LESS documentation: [parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) (with no space it's also a parent selector but it isn't intuitive at all, at least for me: I also thought it was an append mechanism for many months when in fact it's just a consequence of being a parent selector; the most used consequence in fact)

Comment: Or in other words: `&` is *always* "parent selector(s)" with or without space before or after it.