# What does `&#my-id` mean in CSS or SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I inherited some CSS code, which is making use of the `&` character prior to the id name to style it. It looks something like this:

```
&#my-id {
  // Content and attributes
}
```

There are also other instances of it, such as:

```
&:before {
  // content and attributes
}
```

and

```
&:hover {
      // content and attributes
    }
```

What do those mean? I can't find a good way to express this in a search, so I can't find anything. My apologies if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Notice how they're inside other selector blocks. eg. `#something { color:red; &:hover { color:blue; } }` - this should give you a clue. When compiled, you get `#something {color:red} #something:hover {color:blue}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to the parent selector.

Input:

```
.parent {
    &.child {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.parent.child { color: red }
```

It's really helpful if you're writing CSS in BEM format, something like:

```
.block {
    &__element {

        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;

        &--modifier {
             width: 200px;
        }
    }
}

.block__element { width: 100px; height: 100px;}
.block__element--modifier { width: 200px;}

<div class="block__element"></div>
<div class="block__element block__element--modifier"></div>
```

And finally, all examples I've shared have been concatenating the class names, but you can also use it as a reference, like:

```
.parent {
    & .child {
         color: red;
    }
}

.parent {
    .child & {
         color: blue;
    }
}


.parent .child { color: red }
.child .parent { color: blue }
```

Additional references:

http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature

https://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/

[Using the ampersand (SASS parent selector) inside nested selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724861/using-the-ampersand-sass-parent-selector-inside-nested-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

It's a built-in feature of Sass: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

You can use it when you're nesting selectors and you need a more specific selector, like an element that has *both* of two classes:

If your CSS looks like this:

```
.some-class.another-class { }
```

And you wanted to nest, the Sass equivalent is:

```
.some-class {
     &.another-class {}
}
```